# Intel HD & Ubuntu 12.10 = unknown. Tried SNA enable & PPA add

Tags: 12.10, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, intel

I have an Asus K52F with and Intel HD graphics chip. I used the SNA enable trick on 12.04 and it worked without the PPA needing to be added. I've been going at it for 3 days now on 12.10 and tried everything I can think of or find online but it still shows up as Unknown Graphics under Settings --> Details. Does anyone know anything that can fix this. The i915 kernel driver is loading if this makes a difference I don't now.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not in the first post.  Afterwards you can mark you own answer as the right answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've corrected it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Installed `mesa-utils` with `apt-get` and all is good now.